# PyTest: Django transaction commit failure

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, pytest

I am using Pytest to implement unit test in my django project which has MySql as backend.

In combination with these I am making use of SQLAlchemy for data generation.

I have a python function **call_my_flow()** which executes two different flows depending upon conditions. First flow uses sqlalchemy connection and second flow uses django connection for database insert.

I have written two unit tests using pytest to check both the flows.

First flow (where sqlalchemy connection is used): Commits the process flow transaction in database and pytest runs as per expectation.

Second flow (where django database connection is used): The transaction commit fails thus resulting into the failure of test.

Demo code:

```
import pytest
from myflow import call_my_flow

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=False)
def setup_my_flow():
    call_my_flow()    

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup_my_flow")
class TestGenerateOrder(object):
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def setuporder(self):
        self.first_count = 2
        self.second_count = 5    

    @pytest.mark.order1
    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_first_flow_count(self):
        db_count = get_first_count()
        assert db_count == self.first_count    

    @pytest.mark.order2
    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_second_flow_count(self):
        db_count = get_second_count()
        assert db_count == self.second_count
```

Please suggest a solution on the same.